# Azure ServiceBus: Client.Receive() returns null for messages > 64 KB

Tags: c#, message-queue, azureservicebus

I'm using a `BrokeredMessage` containing a `Stream` with a serialized object. According to the documentation the stream is part of the body **not** the header which is restricted to 64 KB. The overall message with about 67 KB is well below the [limit of 256 KB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh694235.aspx) for the message-size of ServiceBus queues.

1. I'm able to send a message and it shows up in the queue with the correct message-size.
2. After issuing the `Receive`-command the packet is removed from the queue and the counter is decremented accordingly. But, the operation runs into a timeout and returns a `null`-pointer instead of the `BrokeredMessage`.

I've tried with a packet with a size of 42 KB and all works well - sending, receiving and deserializing.

**Q** Why doesn't it work with the larger message and how can I make it work?

**Edit 0**

I tried receiving a `byte`-array filled with a random pattern:

```
var bm = new BrokeredMessage(new byte[n])
```

1. `n` = 63500 does work. (*send:* `HeaderSize` = 53, `BodySize` = 63572; *receive:* `HeaderSize` = 139, `BodySize` = 63572)
2. `n` = 64000 does **not** work. (*send:* `HeaderSize` = 54, `BodySize` = 64072; *receive:* `null`)

**Edit 1**

@David Pfeffer It's just as simple as that:

```
var queueWork = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(@"Endpoint=sb://***/;SharedAccessKeyName=***;SharedAccessKey=***", path, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
BrokeredMessage message = queueWork.Receive();
```

Comment: Can you show sample failing code for the receive?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer Please see Edit 1

Comment: You're not using on-premises service bus by any chance, are you?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer No, but I'm hidden behind a firewall...

Comment: IIRC, messages > 64kb < 256kb are chunked. That's why they used to bill by the 64kb block, so a 100kb message would be charged as 2 messages. Not that that information solves your problem, but its an interesting observation that 64kb *is* a magic number for the service bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce this. Here's my sample code:

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://***.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=***", "queue", ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
client.Send(new BrokeredMessage(new byte[100000]));
var msg = client.Receive();
// msg is happy
```